# Instantiate objects in a List and use it

Tags: unity, c#

Why does the following code not work?

I want to instantiate prefabs in a list and then use  it as a GameObject like that :

```
public GameObject prefab;

void Start()
{

 ArrayList players = new ArrayList();

  for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
  {
        players.Add( (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab));
  }

  players[2].transform.position = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);

}
```

there is an error message

[image]

Comment: Also, and I'm not totally sure, but, if your list is only in the `Start` method, most likely the game objects will be removed at the end of the scope.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not super familiar with Unity and c#, but...

> The ArrayList class is designed to hold heterogeneous collections of objects. ([Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.8))

So the only thing your `players` contains, is `object`s (at least w.r.t. the world).

You either want to cast the content before using it:

```
((GameObject)players[2]).transform.position = ...
```

Or use a clearer type like `List<GameObject>`, which will explicitly tell the world that it contains `GameObjects`, and let you do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is not working because you are adding prefabs to another list(numbers)
Your code should be like this

```
void Start()
{

 ArrayList players = new ArrayList();

  for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
  {
        players.Add((GameObject)Instantiate(prefab));
  }

  players[2].transform.position = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);

}
```